# Viewbag type datetime is null but View show empty string and cannot show data (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I have some problems.
I got VIEWBAG from controller and specify and show data as Code
I check on Jquery it show "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

@ViewBag.detail.from_date_go  IS null but Query check through IF the condition is false but why query accept in if
[image]

Comment: The exception is thrown because you call `ToString()` on `null`. In your code, if statement doesn't run at server-side unless you call as `@if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ViewBag.detail.from_date_go)) {...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'@ViewBag.detail.from_date_go' == '' if @ViewBag.detail.from_date_go is null

here all your code are evaluated.
You must check the null on server side. In your code you check in in the client side.

use the '@if' to check the null in razor instead of in javascript.

Example:

```
@if (MyValue != null) {
    //This code will be evaluated only if MyValue is not null
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#MyField').val('@MyValue.ToString()');
    });
    </script>
}
```

the easyest way will be to write the html directly:

```
<input type="text" value='@(MyValue != null ? MyValue.ToString() : "")' />
```

or inside a script tag ...

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        //...
        @if (MyValue != null) {
            @Html.Raw("$('#MyField').val('" + MyValue.ToString() + "');");
        }
        //...
    });
</script>
```

remember : When you use @if, it happen on server side. When you use if it happen in javascript.

hope it help ;-)